# Returning a character array from C++ to C# as function argument

Tags: c#, c++

I have a C++ library that posseses a function that looks like this:

```
int getSomeString( char* someString );
```

The function is returning an error code. `someString` is used as a output argument. 
Now, I need to call this function from C#, so I wrote a wrapper in C++ that exports the function to a dll:

```
__declspec(dllexport) int getSomeStringWrapper( char* someString ) {
    return getSomeString( someString );
}
```

The dll import in my C# project looks like this at the moment:

```
[DllImport( DLL_PATH )]
public static extern int getSomeStringWrapper( [MarshalAs( UnmanagedType.LPStr )]out string someString );

...

static void Main() {
    var value = String.Empty;
    error = getSomeString( out value );
}
```

I also tried using the `StringBuilder` class:

```
[DllImport( DLL_PATH )]
public static extern int getSomeStringWrapper( [MarshalAs( UnmanagedType.LPStr )]out StringBuilder someString );

...

static void Main() {
    int someCapacity = 100;
    var value = new StringBuilder( someCapacity );
    error = getSomeString( out value );
}
```

When I call the imported function, the software freezes and I see the following in the output window: 
`A first chance exception of type 'System.AccessViolationException' occurred in mscorlib.dll`.

How can I get the C++ function to return a string as an output function argument to my C# code?

Comment: Does that C function expect a string of a certain size, or does it expect a null-terminated string?

Comment: @parktomatomi The API does not specify that. I also tried to pass a non empty string, but it did not work as well.

Comment: Have you tried to use the API from native code? I don't see anything obviously wrong with your p/invoke signature.

Comment: *How can I get the C++ function to return a string as an output function argument to my C# code?* -- You should first determine exactly where the error is occurring.  Maybe there isn't a chance to return anything, since the `getSomeString` function may be where the issue is residing.  If `getSomeString` is successful, but on return things go wrong, then that is another scenario.  But you need to determine which scenario it is.